# Recuperar coleccion de un objeto en PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

Estoy trabajando con PL/SQL en Oracle y estoy bloqueado en el siguiente punto:

- Tengo un tipo, el cual a su vez tiene una propiedad que es un tipo tabla de objetos.

Esto representa a un Alumno tiene tiene una serie Notas, las cuales están representadas por la asignatura y la notas en cada una de las evaluaciones.

El código PL/SQL es el siguiente:

```
-- TIPO PARA GUARGAR LA 
-- ASIGNATURA Y NOTAS 
-- DEL ALUMNO
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_NOTAS_AL AS OBJECT(
    ASIG REF T_ASIGNATURA,
    ARRNOTAS V_NOTAS
);

-- TABLA ANIDADA
CREATE TYPE ANI_NOTAS AS TABLE OF T_NOTAS_AL;

-- TIPO ALUMNO
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TP_ALUMNO AS OBJECT(
    DNI VARCHAR2(10),
    NOMBRE VARCHAR2(50),
    DIREC T_DIRECCION,
    ARRTELS V_TELS,
    FECHA_NAC DATE,
    NOTAS ANI_NOTAS,
    CURSO REF T_CURSO
);

-- LOS ALUMNOS SON GUARDADOS EN 
-- UNA TABLA PARA ESTE TIPO
CREATE TABLE TAB_ALUMNOS OF TP_ALUMNO
NESTED TABLE NOTAS STORE AS NEST_ANI_NOTAS;
```

Entonces la pregunta es:
¿Como puedo hacer para acceder desde un procedimiento PL/SQL ajeno al tipo a las notas en cada evaluación?